# C++ Basic issue with variables - only 3 lines of code

Tags: c++, variables

I'm working on my new project now and I'm facing a weird problem. The problem seems to have two solutions - the first one which would take me, let's say, about 5 minutes, and the second one which would require some copying and pasting and take a lot of time.

However, I am not sure if the first solution is possible or not, and mainly, how it's possible.

I wasn't even able to briefly describe my problem to Google, but I'll try to describe it to you.

Let's say I have an **variable x**. Then I have another **variable $9$** (it's name is 9, for example). I want variable $9$ to change it's value, when the value of **variable x** is equal to 9. The code:

**int x = 9

char $9$ = 0

$x$ = 1**  //this in not correct. This is just my idea. This line should do; *char variable with the name which is equal to the value of int x changes its value to 1*..

I can't use **if** (if (x == 9) $9$ = 1;) or **switch** because there are actually 600 possible values for int x and therefore also 600 char $value of x$ variables.. (well, thats the second solution).

I hope atleast somebody understood my issue, any ideas? Thank you very much for any help. Also, I'm sorry for my beginner's english, for being new to C++ and for being unable to google it. :D

Comment: You cannot use a number as a variable name. (Think: if you could, what would `1 + 9` be if `9 = 0`?)

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. Read up on *arrays*.

Comment: I've re-read your post 4 times and still don't understand what you are trying to do. You are trying to programmatically change the name of a variable? Don't do that. Or just have a variable's value change when another variable changes? Just use a pointer to the original variable.

Comment: Can you put all of your values in an array or other collection and then just iterate through it to find all the value that match?

Comment: Jongware: 9+1 would be 10. $9$+1 would be 1.

Comment: Thanks, Im going to check arrays.

Comment: As you found out (the hard way) `$9$` is not valid C++. You may want to review your course notes/study book.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want some sort of key-value store. That is, you have a runtime determined key, and you want to lookup / change some value based on that key. There's a few options included in C++ that can do this relatively easily.

Because your key is an `int` that is relatively restricted in range, we can use an array. We can also use a `std::unordered_map` (a hash table) or a `std::map` (a binary tree).

So... given one of these objects:

```
std::array<int, 600> data;
std::unordered_map<int, int> data;
std::map<int, int> data;
```

We could do:

```
int x = 9;
data[x] = 1;
```